# Pyspark : creating a Nested json file

Tags: pyspark, nested-json

I want to create a nested json file from data in PySpark from the following data.

I wanted to convert this into Nested json file which should have following structure.

```
{    "NewData" : [          {"id":"1","number":"smith","name":"uber","age":12},         {"id":"2","number":"jon","name":"lunch","age":13},          {"id":"3","number":"jocelyn","name":"rental","age":15},         {"id":"4","number":"megan","name":"sds","age":15}
             ]  }
```

How to put the correct output in a json file

Can you help me achieve this?

```
data = [(1,12,"smith", "uber"),
         (2,13,"jon","lunch"),
         (3,15,"jocelyn","rental"),
         (4,15,"megan","sds")
         ]
 
 
 schema = StructType([
 StructField('id', IntegerType(), True),
 StructField('age', IntegerType(), True),
 StructField('number', StringType(), True),
 StructField('name', StringType(), True)
                     ])

 df = spark.createDataFrame(data,schema)
 
 df.show(truncate=False)

 df = df.withColumn("NewData", F.lit("NewData"))
 
 df2 = df.groupBy('NewData').agg(F.collect_list(
 F.to_json(F.struct('id','number', 'name', 'age'))
                           ).alias('values')
                 ))
 
 df2.show(truncate=False)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to use `to_json` function as this function results `string json object`.

- `groupBy` -> on constant value
- `agg()` -> with alias name as `Newdata`

**`Example:`**

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *
data = [(1,12,"smith", "uber"),
         (2,13,"jon","lunch"),
         (3,15,"jocelyn","rental"),
         (4,15,"megan","sds")
         ]
 
 
schema = StructType([
 StructField('id', IntegerType(), True),
 StructField('age', IntegerType(), True),
 StructField('number', StringType(), True),
 StructField('name', StringType(), True)
                     ])

df = spark.createDataFrame(data,schema)
 
df.show(truncate=False)
     
df2 = df.groupBy(lit(1)).agg(collect_list(struct('id','number', 'name', 'age')).alias('NewData')).\
  drop("1")
 
df2.write.mode("overwrite").format("json").save("<directory_path>")

print(dbutils.fs.head("<file_path>"))
#{"NewData":[{"id":1,"number":"smith","name":"uber","age":12},{"id":2,"number":"jon","name":"lunch","age":13},{"id":3,"number":"jocelyn","name":"rental","age":15},{"id":4,"number":"megan","name":"sds","age":15}]}
```

Comment: Thx a lot.
This is exactly what I wanted in my output.
I missed the trick of 'drop("1")'.
Thx again.